# Swift: Not able to dismiss modally presented LoginViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

As SplitViewController loads, I am showing a Login Screen. On successful login, I need to go back to parent view controller. Somehow dismissal is not working for me. Here is the code:

**ParentViewController:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if !appDelegate.loggedIn {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginScreen", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
```

**Child ViewController:**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.loggedIn = true
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

The dismissal part never works. It just hangs on Login Screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:

1) remove self.   keep only dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

or remove self. and make it:

2) presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
or remove self. and try:

3) presentedViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your parent view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if !appDelegate.loggedIn {
            let loginVC: UIViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as UIViewController
            loginVC = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
            self.parentViewController?.presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
}
```

You're instantiating the new view controller by its own name rather than by the segue name.